# Firefox anchor sinking on ":active"

Tags: html, css, firefox

Faced with the problem in firefox.

You can see it here: [link](http://codepen.io/css-tricks/pen/GtHfd)

On click and hold the text "Click Me" goes down on one pixel. If you move away your cursor while holding the mouse button and release it on empty space - the text "Click Me" won't go up on one pixel. It will after you click on other element or empty space. 
Chrome does not have this kind of behavior.

Including images to get it more clearer:

1.While clicked on text and after button release on empty space
[image: While clicked on text and after button release on empty space]

2.On idle and after clicking on other element
[image: On idle and after clicking on other element]

**OS:** Windows 8.1

**Browser version:** 33.1

Code:

```
<a href="#">Click Me</a>
a { 
  position: relative;
}
a:active {
  top: 1px;
}
```

Comment: Tried to wrap it in `span` with `hover` attr, but it still buggy enough in FF http://htmlbank.net/?CW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This is a known idiosyncrasy of Firefox, you can find more about it [here](http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/tests/css2/sec05-11-03.htm)*

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y03humnv/5/)**

**HTML**

```
<div onclick="location.href='#';" class="link">W3C Web server</div>
```

Change the CSS to this,

```
.link {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.link:active {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
}
```

Comment: Now when it is active and you hover it up - it acts like it is pressing

Comment: @eatmypants Updated answer again... instead of using `<a>` use  `<div>` for links with `class='link'`. Hope this helps :)